# How to remove UIPageViewController's Bounce effect in iOS for Swift 3/4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipageviewcontroller, bounce

Here is the screenshot of my issue:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find scrollview inside your UIPageViewController and add UIScrollViewDelegate

```
for view in self.pageViewController!.view.subviews {
        if let subView = view as? UIScrollView {
            subView.delegate = self
            subView.isScrollEnabled = true
            subView.bouncesZoom = false

        }
}
```

(Extends UIScrollViewDelegate in your ViewController class)

For UIScrollViewDelegate on method "scrollViewDidScroll" and "scrollViewWillEndDragging" you can add something like this

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if(currentIndex == 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.x < scrollView.bounds.size.width){
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:scrollView.bounds.size.width, y:0.0)
    }else if(currentIndex == 2 && scrollView.contentOffset.x > scrollView.bounds.size.width) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:scrollView.bounds.size.width, y:0.0)
    }
}

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    if(currentIndex == 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.x < scrollView.bounds.size.width){
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:scrollView.bounds.size.width, y:0.0)
    }else if(currentIndex == 2 && scrollView.contentOffset.x > scrollView.bounds.size.width) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:scrollView.bounds.size.width, y:0.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this like following code.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
if currentIndex == 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.x < scrollView.bounds.size.width {
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
} else if currentIndex == totalViewControllers - 1 && scrollView.contentOffset.x > scrollView.bounds.size.width {
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
    }
}
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    if currentIndex == 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.x < scrollView.bounds.size.width {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
    } else if currentIndex == totalViewControllers - 1 && scrollView.contentOffset.x > scrollView.bounds.size.width {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!